# SFTP reverse proxy

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, sftp

Serverfaulters.

Short: I'd like to publish several SFTP servers through one server (reverse proxy/relay). How could I do that?

Long: there are three components:

```
                                    ----> sftp-server1.local
                                    |     port: 22
Filezilla  ----> sftp-proxy.org ----
SFTP client      port: 22           |
                                    ----> sftp-server2.local
                                          port: 22
```

- Filezilla - SFTP client
- sftp-proxy.org - available from the internet server
- sftp-server*.local - internal SFTP servers
- sftp-user* - user accounts on SFTP servers

Case: internet user opens Filezilla, enters `sftp-proxy.org` with login `sftp-user1` and gets on `sftp-server1.local`. Another user enters sftp-proxy.org with login `sftp-user2` and gets on `sftp-server2.local`. So SFTP-proxy.org redirects user to internal SFTP server based on his username.

I've found this `sshd_config` for sftp-proxy.org:

```
Match User sftp-user1
    ForceCommand ssh -t sftp-user1@sftp-server1.local $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
Match User sftp-user2
    ForceCommand ssh -t sftp-user2@sftp-server2.local $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

But they say it won't work, is that so?

Note: I would like to find the solution that client is user friendly (default Filezilla, no ssh options).

Comment: any error log or error message?

Comment: The configuration seems good to me, except that you may be better suited by creating groups of users and doing the match on the group otherwise it means all of your users will need to share login `sftp-user1` and some for the others.